# 'Start debugging Android application' does not work

Tags: xamarin

When i try to deploy my App to a device i get a message that says 'Start debugging Android application', but the App doesn't open on my device(physical phone).

The issue started recently. Visual Studio once showed a message that says 'Something mono is making Visual studio to run slowly, and i must turn it off'. So i turned it off, then this issue started to occur.

Please help ?

[image]

Comment: Facing this issue in VS 2017

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fix the issue by repairing(installing) Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Still working on it, here there are some pending posts and workarounds about this issue/bug:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92239/visual-studio-freezes-on-start-debugging-android-application
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1547
After a few minutes of halt it finally works but it's a real pain!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates > search for Mono Debugging for Visual Studio Enable it and restart the Visual Studio

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.15. I can't see Tools > Extensions and Updates > Mono Debugging for Visual Studio. Did you have any ideas?

Comment: The Extensions and Updates are moved in Extensions > Manage Extensions, but I have no clue, this is an answer from more than a year ago :)